# expecting variable (T_VARIABLE) in /home/pirmansa/laravel/vendor/ramsey/uuid/src/functions.php on line 34

Tags: php

> [29-May-2020 10:08:44 UTC] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '?', expecting variable (T_VARIABLE) in /home/pirmansa/laravel/vendor/ramsey/uuid/src/functions.php on line 34

Comment: Welcome to SO !  People expect to see what you tried (your code), in a well formatted question. Help them help you. Please take the [**stack overflow tour**](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) to know more about this site, and read about **[how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)**.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48670368/5947043 is the specific answer that you need from the mentioned duplicate question. Basically you need to upgrade to PHP 7 before you can use this code. But you should be doing that anyway because [PHP 5 is not supported anymore](https://www.php.net/supported-versions.php). (And for future reference, simply typing `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '?'` into google would have told you the answer without us needing to point you to it. Please always google your error messages - you are almost never the first person to experience it or ask about it.